# Error loading image resource on device

Tags: sprite-kit

At the start of my game I preload all the textures with preloadWithCompletionHandler method on SKTextureAtlas instance. The textures seem ok on all simulators and iPhone 4S and above devices. Only on iPhone 4 device, I see red crosses everywhere and get **"SKTexture: Error loading image resource"** errors for every sprite I load.

I tried cleaning the project, deleting the app and debugging again, creating an IPA and running that way, to no avail. iPhone 4 can't show the textures.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is the textures are too large. The iPhone 4 can load textures up to 2048x2048 pixels in size. Newer devices can handle up to 4096x4096 textures.

If that's the problem exclude iPhone 4 from supported devices or split your textures into smaller chunks.

Comment: Thanks @LearnCocos2D. There is only one texture and it's 2048x2048. So something else is going on there.